# ionice disk access priority manipulation

Tags: disk

With the ionice command, I can adjust priority for disk access, similar to how nice and renice set priority for CPU access. They say disk access, but I'm not sure what it means. Does it mean what a program gets file from the disk like sda1, sda2 or so?? I have several disk, so what disk specifically do Ubuntu know what I want?? Finally why setting the disk access priority to Real Time(1) is considered to be prone to lose data??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ionice sets the priority for all I/O operations. You can't set it for a specific disk. It's bit similar to using `nice` on a system with more than one processors.

Processes with class 3 (Idle) will only get disk time if no other program has asked for I/O for some time. On a busy system that may mean they'll never get I/O time. This class is often used for programs doing housekeeping tasks in the background.

Among the class 2 (Best-effort) programs I/O time is distributed according to the priority level (the `-n` parameter). That's the default.

Class 1 (Realtime) have absolute priority and always get disk time whenever they want. A program in this class that is doing a lot of I/O  can block other programs from getting enough disk time to save its data and therefor cause data loss.

Class 0 is basically the same as class 2.